# Error 1452 when updating a parent table using mariaDB

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb, cascade, composite-key

I get error 1452 when updating a row in a parent table when running mariaDB 10.5.8. The tables are defined as follows:

```sql
> SHOW CREATE TABLE files;
files   CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `file_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `md5` text NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_path`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

```sql
> SHOW CREATE TABLE headlines;
headlines   CREATE TABLE `headlines` (
  `file_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `headline_offset` int(11) NOT NULL,
  -- other columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_path`,`headline_offset`),
  CONSTRAINT `headlines_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`file_path`) REFERENCES `files` (`file_path`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

```sql
> SHOW CREATE TABLE headline_closures;
headline_closures   CREATE TABLE `headline_closures` (
  `file_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `headline_offset` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_offset` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `depth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_path`,`headline_offset`,`parent_offset`),
  KEY `file_path` (`file_path`,`parent_offset`),
  CONSTRAINT `headline_closures_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`file_path`, `headline_offset`) REFERENCES `headlines` (`file_path`, `headline_offset`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `headline_closures_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`file_path`, `parent_offset`) REFERENCES `headlines` (`file_path`, `headline_offset`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The contents of the database (minimal example):

```sql
> SELECT * FROM files;
/path/to/foo1.org   106e9f12c9e4ff3333425115d148fbd4    6

> SELECT * FROM headlines;
/path/to/foo1.org   1   --other columns

> SELECT * FROM headline_closures;
/path/to/foo1.org   1   1   0
```

Executing the following produces the error (expected behavior is that the file path changes for all tables per the `CASCADE` clauses):

```sql
> UPDATE files SET file_path='/path/to/foo2.org' WHERE md5='106e9f12c9e4ff3333425115d148fbd4';
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`org_sql`.`headline_closures`, CONSTRAINT `headline_closures_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`file_path`, `parent_offset`) REFERENCES `headlines` (`file_path`, `headline_offset`))
```

Things I've tried (per [MySQL cascade update failed when foreign key column referenced in composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600963/mysql-cascade-update-failed-when-foreign-key-column-referenced-in-composite-prim))

1. Removing the second `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` from the `headline_closures` table (same error)
2. Dropping the primary key from the `headline_closures` table and that produced `error 150 (Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)`

I thought (1) would work because the docs state to not have multiple `CASCADE`s that could change a single column; I'm not sure why (2) would work. What am I not getting here?

Also, if someone could explain why this same arrangement works for SQLite and postgreSQL that would be appreciated since I don't get the same error with those ;)

#### Edit 1

- This same behavior happens with MySQL 8.0.22 (so not just a mariaDB error, not too surprising)
- I don't get the error if I take away one of the foreign keys in `headline_closures` (so there is still one constraint that has `ON UPDATE CASCADE`)
- If I remove the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` from `headline_closures_ibfk_1` instead of `headline_closures_ibfk_2`, the error then complains about `headline_closures_ibfk_1` (where it complained about `headline_closures_ibfk_2` when I took the `CASCADE`s away from `headline_closures_ibfk_2` or if I left them on both) so it seem that the error is due to updating the parent, having the cascade propagate to the `headline_closures` table where the second constraint doesn't see the update and therefore complains (or something)

#### Edit 2:

- `DELETE FROM files WHERE md5='106e9f12c9e4ff3333425115d148fbd4';` works as intended with the constraints as written above (no error and the the deletion propagates to all child tables).

Comment: Sometimes it is better to take control of "cascading this and that" instead of hoping the FK definition works the way you expect.

Comment: @RickJames please explain this; do you mean updating each table manually where I want?

Comment: Do your own `DELETE` as a separate, explicit, statement.  (And remove the `CASCADEs`.)

Comment: @RickJames see edits, `DELETE` works as intended; I'm having problems with just `UPDATE` statements